# Calculating contrast values on Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am currently studying experimental designs in statistics and I am calculating values pertaining to 2^3 factorial designs.

The question that I have is particularly with the calculations of the "contrasts".

My goal of this question is to learn how to use the table "Coded Factors" and "Total" in order to get the values "Contrast" using the IF THEN function in Excel.

[image]

For example, Contrast A is calculated as : x - y . Where
x = sum of the values in the Total, where the Coded Factor A is + .
And y= sum of the values in the Total, where the Coded Factor A is - .

This would be rather simple, but for the interactions it is a bit more complex.

For example, contrast AC is obtained as : x - y . Where
x = sum of the values in the Total, where the product of Coded Factor A and that of C becomes + .
And y = sum of the values in the Total, where the product of Coded Factor A and that of B becomes - .

I would really appreciate your help.

Edited:
Considering the way how IF statements work, I thought that it might be a good idea to convert the + into 1 and  - into -1 to make the calculation straight forward.

Comment: Do you mean "contrast AB" instead of "contrast AC" ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert all +/- to 1/-1. Use some cells as helper..

Put in these formulas :

```
J2  -->  =LEFT(J1)
K2  -->  =MID(J1,2,1)
L2  -->  =MID(J1,3,1)
```

Put

```
J3  -->  =IF(J$2="",1,INDEX($B3:$D3,MATCH(J$2,$B$2:$D$2,0)))
```

and drag to L10. Then

```
M3  -->  =J3*K3*L3*G3
```

and drag to M10. Lastly,

```
M1  -->  =SUM(M3:M10)
```

How to use : Input the Factor comb in cell **J1** and the result will be in **M1**.

Idea : separate the factor text > load the multiplier > multiply Total values with multiplier > get sum.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does It work? If it doesn't share me where you're stuck. (: